# testsaslauthd - permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, saslauthd

> Running: Ubuntu 12.10 32bits server version.

I'm trying to connect to the saslauthd and getting the error I mentioned on the title (permission denied).

`$ /usr/sbin/testsaslauthd -u myuser -p mypassword`

`connect() : Permission denied`

However when I try to connect as root (sudo), it connects successfully.

I need to be able to connect as a user.

Any thought?

Answer (score 2):

In order to communicate with saslauthd you have to be member of the group sasl.

Adding `sudo -g sasl` to the `testsaslauthd` command made it work.